# PDF Generator Python for Specific Template and compatible for ec2 AWS

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pdf-generation

I have a template where I have to fill this form from web information and generate pdf using python. I have seen in different forum regarding generation however that does not have compatability with ec2 AWS?

Your suggestion is appreciated. Here is the template looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwxtE.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What you are asking is not clear.

Comment: In fact, from the web, I take the input forms: date, name, tasks and project and others... and I have to generate the pdf report with some static information and dynamic form information, and send this report to the users.